# What does it mean that dwarf speed isn't reduced by heavy armor?

Tags: dnd-5e, dwarf

In the PHB p.20

> Speed. Your base walking speed is 25 feel. **Your
>   speed is not reduced by wearing heavy armor.**

The thing is I cant seem to find anywhere that heavy armor reduces speed. So to what is this referring to?